# Find $[\mathbb Q (\xi ^2 ) : \mathbb Q ]$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, group-extensions

Where $\xi = e^{\frac{\pi}3i}$ and $L=\mathbb Q (\xi ^2 )$

I want to find the minimal polynomial of $L$ over $\mathbb Q$ and then this will determine the degree of the field.

But I am not sure how to do it. Normally if we have something like $\mathbb Q (\sqrt2)$, we would let $x=\sqrt2 $ and then keep squaring (or other power value) both sides until we have a rational on the RHS. In this case, we just square it once. Then prove that its irreducible which is easy if the degree of the  polynomial is $2$ or $3$.

But in our case, I don't think it works like that.

Please help.

Comment: Raising to power $ 6 $ does work. You have $ \xi^6 = 1 $, so $ \xi^2 $ is a root of $ t^3-1 $, and hence a root of $ t^2+t+1 $. Now, is the last polynomial irreducible over Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\gamma=\xi^2$, then $\gamma^3-1=\left(e^{2\frac{\pi}{3}}\right)^3-1=e^{2\pi}-1=1-1=0$. So $\gamma$ is a root of $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$, and since $\gamma\not\in \mathbb{Q}$, the minimal polynomial is $x^2+x+1$, and finally $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2$.

Comment: and the $x^2 +x +1$ is irreducible over Q because its roots which are $x=-0.5 \pm \sqrt{-0.75}$ are not in Q right????

Comment: @snowman Right!

Comment: Sorry to ask further but if say $\xi = e^{\frac{\pi}4 i}$, then it would actually be easier to find it right? Because we have $x=\xi^2$ and then $x^2=-1$ so $x^2+1$ is our min polynomial right?

Comment: Have in mind that $\left(e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}\right)^2=e^{2\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}i}=e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}=(\cos \frac{\pi}{2}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{2})=0+i\cdot 1=i$. So, yeah, $x^2+1$ is the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $$ (\xi^2)^3=1$$

So $\xi^2$ is a root of $X^3-1$. Can you factor this polynomial? Which factor does have $\xi^2$ as a root?